# How to bring square shape using div and and align text right using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, sencha-touch

How to bring  square shape using div and and align text right using css?

I want to display like chart legend 
squareshapeimage(Using div)  Legend Text

I have tried below way but font is coming in below

```
<div> <div vertical-align: middle; margin-bottom: 0.75em; style="width:5%; height:5%; margin-top:4%; margin-left:3%; padding-bottom:5%;background-color:red"> </div> <span>Present</span> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this ?

```css
.a {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.a span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: -10px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <span>Present:</span>
</div>
```